# I am trying to calculate sine of an angle without using the Math.sin() in java

Tags: java, math, logic, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate sine of an angle without using the Math.sin(). I got stuck in it's equation as I keep getting the wrong results

note I have a method that changes the angle from degrees to radians

```
public static double sin(double x, int precision) {
 //this method is simply the sine function
    double answer = 1, power = 1;
    int n = 2,factorial = 1;

    while (n<=precision) {

        power = (power * x * x *-1) +1 ; 
        factorial = (factorial * (n +1))* (n-1);
          answer = answer + ((power/factorial ));

        n = n + 2;

    }

    return answer;

}
```

Comment: IIRC that series converge only slowly why not use CORDIC or bin search instead?

Comment: This equation is not the Taylor series expansion that I'd expect to see.  Where did you get this?  It's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're attempting to calculate the sine of angle given in radians using the [Maclaurin series](http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/maclaurin-expansion-of-sinx/), a special case of Taylor series.

```
sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + ...
```

Your initial `answer` is `1` when it should be `x`.  Your initial `power` is `1` when it should be `x` also.

```
double answer = x, power = x;
```

For some reason you're adding one to the `power` part of the result when you shouldn't be.

```
power = (power * x * x * -1);
```

You'll also need to fix your `factorial` calculation.  Multiply by `n + 1` and `n`, not `n + 1` and `n - 1`.

```
factorial = (factorial * (n + 1)) * (n);
```

With these fixes, testing:

```
for (double angle = 0; angle <= Math.PI; angle += Math.PI / 4)
{
    System.out.println("sin(" + angle + ") = " + sin(angle, 10));
}
```

The results are pretty good considering the limitations of precision for floating point arithmetic.

```
sin(0.0) = 0.0
sin(0.7853981633974483) = 0.7071067811796194
sin(1.5707963267948966) = 0.999999943741051
sin(2.356194490192345) = 0.7070959900908971
sin(3.141592653589793) = -4.4516023820965686E-4
```

Note that this will get more inaccurate as the values of `x` get larger, not just because of the inaccuracy to represent pi, but also because of the floating point calculations for adding and subtracting large values.

Comment: Great job, but even the factorial is a bad idea.  There's a better way to do this.  You have the right idea, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help you where right !! and yes I am using the maclaurin series

Comment: @duffymo Yes, there are other ways to optimize/improve this, even just taking advantage of the symmetry of the sine function, e.g. sin(x) = sin(π - x), sin(-x) = -sin(x).  At least this method isn't calculating the factorial from scratch each iteration; it's an iterative calculation.