# Express Maclauren Series As Java Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I saw another undergraduate [attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435077/i-am-trying-to-calculate-sin-of-an-angle-without-using-the-math-sin-in-java/49435370#comment85872675_49435370) to calculate a sine function without using the Java Math.sin function the other day.

It drives me nuts to see factorial functions used in these efforts.  I decided to throw together my own.  It worked out well enough, but now I'd love to see if I could express this as a Java lambda.

Performing operations on a stream of integers is straightforward.   I'm stuck on how to make the result of the previous term available to the one that follows.

My fear is that such an arrangement would, by definition, preclude any use of `parallelStream`, but that's a sacrifice I'm willing to make.

I'd appreciate any suggestions or advice.

```
/**
 * TaylorSeries for trig functions using lambdas
 * User: MDUFFY
 * Date: 3/22/2018
 * Time: 3:27 PM
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435077/i-am-trying-to-calculate-sin-of-an-angle-without-using-the-math-sin-in-java/49435370#comment85872675_49435370
 */
public class TaylorSeries {

    private static final int DEFAULT_NUM_TERMS = 20;

    private TaylorSeries() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numTerms = 21;
        double x = 0.0;
        double dx = Math.PI/2/(numTerms+1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= numTerms; ++i) {
            double expected_sin = Math.sin(x);
            double actual_sin = TaylorSeries.sin(x, DEFAULT_NUM_TERMS);
            double error_sin = Math.abs(expected_sin-actual_sin);
            double expected_cos = Math.cos(x);
            double actual_cos = TaylorSeries.cos(x, DEFAULT_NUM_TERMS);
            double error_cos = Math.abs(expected_cos - actual_cos);
            String format = "expected: %10.8f actual: %10.8f error: %10.8e";
            String message_sin = String.format(format, expected_sin, actual_sin, error_sin);
            String message_cos = String.format(format, expected_cos, actual_cos, error_cos);
            System.out.println(String.format("angle: %10.8f sin: %s cos: %s", x, message_sin, message_cos));
            x += dx;
        }
    }

    public static double sin(double radians, int n) {
        if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of terms must be positive");
        double value = 0.0;
        double term = radians;
        double x = radians*radians;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            value += term;
            term *= -x/(2*(i+1))/(2*(i+1)+1);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static double cos(double radians, int n) {
        if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of terms must be positive");
        double value = 0.0;
        double term = 1.0;
        double x = radians*radians;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            value += term;
            term *= -x/(2*i+1)/(2*i+2);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You’d have to do something hideous like use Stream.iterate() where the type of the stream is an object with 2 fields (index and term).

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to rewrite this as a stream. Also, you can move the radians*radians out of the for loop.

Comment: Good point, Paul.  Thank you.  I'll do that.  Why?  As a fun exercise to practice with lambdas.  You are quite correct: It's unnecessary.